# Issue with CSS -webkit-radial-gradient closest-side option in Chrome 18 dev

Tags: google-chrome, css, radial-gradients

Is `closest-side` still a valid option for `radial-gradient`? Up until the latest dev release of Chrome (18.0.1003.1 dev) the following `radial-gradient` worked:

```
-webkit-radial-gradient( center -12px, circle closest-side, white 0, black 38px );
```

And produced this effect:
[image]
Now, after updating to 18.0.1003.1 dev, it's producing this:
[image]
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/cn6C8/

Firefox, Safari, and Opera (with their respective prefixes) are still working properly. The other three options -- `closest-corner, farthest-side,` and `farthest-corner` -- still work as expected, and so does no option.

The [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/radial-gradient) page at MDN still shows this as the correct format and still lists `closest-side` as a valid option. I've got one confirmation of this behavior (in comments below) and I can't find anything in the Chrome Forums. Is this option being removed or is this a Chrome bug?

UPDATE (2011-01-16): I've created a case for this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110341
UPDATE (2011-01-20): The case has been assigned, but no verification on its status as a bug.

Comment: Just to confirm that this is different for me too, worked on 17, updated to 18 and now doesn't.

Comment: Though I can't say for sure, my experience with these seemingly random types of bugs in dev chrome builds is that it is a regression and is usually fixed within the week.

Answer (score 1):

A deep search through google yielded several other forums and coding group sites where the same bug is reported. As AlexanderZ said, it is a bug indeed but there is no official explanation or statement about it from the chrome dev team yet.